# golang array referencing eg. b[1:4] references elements 1,2,3

Tags: go

The golang blog states :

"A slice can also be formed by "slicing" an existing slice or array. Slicing is done by specifying a half-open range with two indices separated by a colon. For example, the expression b[1:4] creates a slice including elements 1 through 3 of b (the indices of the resulting slice will be 0 through 2)."

Can someone please explain to me the logic in the above. IE. Why doesn't b[1:4] reference elements 1 through 4? Is this consistent with other array referencing?

Comment: same thing in Python. b[1:4] is elements 1 through 3

Comment: See also: [Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) on why array indices should start at 0.

Comment: @nmichaels More relevantly, Dijkstra explains in that note why the upper bound of a slice should be exclusive: if it weren't, we would have to express the empty slice as [0:-1]. He also notes other advantages: the difference between the bounds is the length of the slice, and adjacent slices have upper bound of one == lower bound of the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is given in the Go Language Specification section on [Slices](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Slices).

> For a string, array, or slice a, the
>   primary expression
>
> ```
>     a[low : high]
> ```
>
> constructs a substring or slice. The
>   index expressions low and high select
>   which elements appear in the result.
>   The result has indexes starting at 0
>   and length equal to high - low.
>
> For convenience, any of the index
>   expressions may be omitted. A missing
>   low index defaults to zero; a missing
>   high index defaults to the length of
>   the sliced operand.

It's easy and efficient to calculate the length of the slice as high - low.

Answer (score 9):

Indexes point to the "start" of the element. This is shared by all languages using zero-based indexing:

```
       | 0 | first | 1 | second | 2 | third | 3 | fourth | 4 | fifth | 5 |
[0]   =  ^
[0:1] =  ^ --------> ^
[1:4] =              ^-------------------------------------> ^  
[0:5] =  ^ ----------------------------------------------------------> ^
```

It's also common to support negative indexing, although Go doesn't allow this:

```
       |-6 |       |-5 |        |-4 |       |-3 |        |-2 |       |-1 |
       | 0 | first | 1 | second | 2 | third | 3 | fourth | 4 | fifth | 5 |
```

Answer (score 4):

Half-open intervals make sense for many reasons, when you get down to it. For instance, with a half-open interval like this, the number of elements is:

```
n = end - start
```

which is a pretty nice and easy formula. For a closed interval, it would be:

```
n = (end - start) + 1
```

which is (not a lot, but still) more complicated.

It also means that for e.g. a string, the entire string is `[1, len(s)]` which also seems intuitive. If the interval was closed, to get the entire string you would need `[1, len(s) + 1]`.

Comment: Wouldn't the definition for a closed-interval system to get the whole string be [1, len(s) - 1]?

Comment: @chaos95: I don't think so ... Then the length of the string would be (len(s) - 1) - 1 + 1 which is len(s) - 1, a contradiction.

Comment: @chaos95 @unwind You're both wrong; check your length formulae. For a half-open interval, the bounds of the entire string are [0, len(s)] (0-indexed) or [1, len(s)+1] (1-indexed). For a closed interval, the bounds are [0, len(s) - 1] (0-indexed) or [1, len(s)] (1-indexed).

Answer (score 2):

Go uses [half-open intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-open_interval) for slices like many other languages.  In a more mathematical notation, the slice `b[1:4]` is the interval `[1,4)` which excludes the upper endpoint.

Comment: One (minor) advantage is that you know it has (4-1)=3 elements in it.