# GoLang Array Index on Struct

Tags: arrays, go, struct

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Bar struct {
    high float64
    low  float64
}

func main() {
    var bars = []Bar{}
    bars = []Bar{
        {1.0, 2.0},
        {1.1, 2.1},
        {1.2, 2.2},
        {1.3, 2.3},
        {1.4, 2.4},
        {1.5, 2.5},
    }
    fmt.Println(bars)
    testFunction(&bars)
}

func testFunction(array *[]Bar) {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(*array[i])
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MZwaFALHfuy

Why can I not access the array row?

invalid operation: array[i] (type *[]Bar does not support indexing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line in for loop to `fmt.Println((*array)[i])`

`*array[i]` would try to dereference `[i]`

`(*array)[i]` would derefence the `array` which is your pointer.

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/yr6WbtS3Aq_c

Comment: Array in function is not the row index.  How would you get access to the second element in the row since you can not do [i][]i] ?

Comment: fmt.Println((*array)[i].low) .  Those are Bar structs, with values for high and low.  While you initialize them in what looks like an array or a slice, they aren't arrays, they are of type Bar.

Comment: I was looking at the array like #7 on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868927/golang-array-referencing-eg-b14-references-elements-1-2-3